# iptables rules not dropping IPs

Tags: server, ssh

I have a trusty 14.04.3 LTS server with fail2ban running.
I have been under attack from 43.229.53.71; the last octet can change.
My auth.log files show entries like this:

```
Dec 11 15:02:51 M1 sshd[5138]: Failed password for root from 43.229.53.71 port 39734 ssh2
Dec 11 15:02:51 M1 sshd[5138]: pam_winbind(sshd:auth): getting password (0x00000388)
Dec 11 15:02:51 M1 sshd[5138]: pam_winbind(sshd:auth): pam_get_item returned a password
Dec 11 15:02:51 M1 sshd[5138]: pam_winbind(sshd:auth): request wbcLogonUser failed: WBC_ERR_AUTH_ERROR, PAM error: PAM_USER_UNKNOWN (10), NTSTATUS: NT_STATUS_NO_SUCH_USER, Error message was: No such user
Dec 11 15:02:53 M1 sshd[5138]: Failed password for root from 43.229.53.71 port 39734 ssh2
Dec 11 15:02:53 M1 sshd[5138]: Received disconnect from 43.229.53.71: 11:  [preauth]
Dec 11 15:02:53 M1 sshd[5138]: PAM 2 more authentication failures; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=43.229.53.71  user=root
```

Here are my iptables rules:

```
root@M1:/etc# iptables -nvL --line-numbers
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 7736 packets, 6163K bytes)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
1        0     0 fail2ban-mysqld-auth  tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            multiport dports 3306
2       45  2838 fail2ban-apache-overflows  tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            multiport dports 80,443
3       45  2838 fail2ban-apache-noscript  tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            multiport dports 80,443
4       45  2838 fail2ban-apache-multiport  tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            multiport dports 80,443
5     1581  100K fail2ban-ssh-ddos  tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            multiport dports 22
6     5080 5449K fail2ban-pam-generic  tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
7     1581  100K fail2ban-ssh  tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            multiport dports 22
8        0     0 REJECT     tcp  --  *      *       43.225.53.71         0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:22 reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
9        0     0 REJECT     tcp  --  *      *       43.225.0.0/16        0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:22 reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
10       0     0 DROP       all  --  *      *       43.225.0.0/16        0.0.0.0/0
11       0     0 DROP       all  --  *      *       43.225.0.0/16        0.0.0.0/0
12       0     0 DROP       all  --  *      *       43.225.53.71         0.0.0.0/0
13       0     0 DROP       all  --  *      *       43.225.53.71         0.0.0.0/0

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 5703 packets, 4217K bytes)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain fail2ban-apache-multiport (1 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
1       45  2838 RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain fail2ban-apache-noscript (1 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
1       45  2838 RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain fail2ban-apache-overflows (1 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
1       45  2838 RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain fail2ban-mysqld-auth (1 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
1        0     0 RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain fail2ban-pam-generic (1 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
1     5080 5449K RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain fail2ban-ssh (1 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
1     1581  100K RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain fail2ban-ssh-ddos (1 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
1     1581  100K RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
```

When I enable SSH, they start attacking as shown in the logs.
Why are the packets from this IP range not being dropped?
I must be missing something simple, any ideas ?

Answer (score 1):

The only rules that could drop/reject SSH packets are:

```
8        0     0 REJECT     tcp  --  *      *       43.225.53.71         0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:22 reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
9        0     0 REJECT     tcp  --  *      *       43.225.0.0/16        0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:22 reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
10       0     0 DROP       all  --  *      *       43.225.0.0/16        0.0.0.0/0
11       0     0 DROP       all  --  *      *       43.225.0.0/16        0.0.0.0/0
12       0     0 DROP       all  --  *      *       43.225.53.71         0.0.0.0/0
13       0     0 DROP       all  --  *      *       43.225.53.71         0.0.0.0/0
```

while your unwanted guest's IP is 43.229.53.71. Note the difference in the second octet: 229 != 225.

Comment: Quite common if you've been looking at something for too long :) Good luck!